# Why does Graham Scan not extend to three dimensions?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

The [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) algorithm computes the convex hull of a finite sets of points. It works only in the plane but is also fast (time $O(n \log n)$).

An old exam question asks, why does the algorithm not extend for three dimensional space? I just can't find an answer; it seems to me as if it should work.

- Sorting the points according to a pivot should not be a problem.
- Detecting a Left/Right turn (or measering the inner angle) neither.

Then what is the problem when we try to extend the algorithm to three dimensions?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: i added the wiki link for Graham Scan.

Comment: Detecting left/right also not ? How ? I dont think so. I guess you are talking about the projection of points on a 2-D hyperplane. Also, in 3D, you will not consider left and right only.

Comment: There is no natural linear ordering of the points on a surface homeomorphic to a sphere.  It would not be clear which point to add next, nor clear whether to accept a point and push further.

Comment: i dont understand why it should be a problem to sort them according to 2 choosen axis (e.g. according to (x/y)). And when detecting (just literally) left/right we can take into account the z-coordinate. Am i right?

Comment: What does "left" and "right" mean in three-dimensional space?

Comment: @Raphael, if you fix two axis (e.g. x and y), then you can decide if you go to left or right in z. That was what i meant.

Comment: And why not fix x and z? How do you decide for a specific plane to project on, and why is that always the correct thing to do?

Comment: Does it matter which two axis i fix? Even if i do the fixing for all variations [(x,y), z for left/right], [(x,z), y for left/right] etc., i can compare the results at the end in 3 steps.